# Why do some commands 'hang' the terminal until attached storage spins up?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, command-line

I have wondered this for a while and haven't found an answer. I open terminal and enter a command and before the command returns a result my external HDD spins up. The OS is not running off that HDD. The command `man lsof` doesn't need to access the external HDD as far as I know. Running the command a second time doesn't cause this to happen.

Any ideas?

Nothing in my PATH that points to the external HDD:

```
$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/libexec/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/opt/nano/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Comment: Is there anything in your `$PATH` that points to your external drive?

Comment: I added the contents of `$PATH` above. The external HDD is an encrypted Time Machine USB hard drive if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'd bet that any command would wait until the external HDD had spun up. This is to say, I suspect the situation is not command dependent.